# Including ssh-agent in .profile at boot

Tags: bash, 20.04, .profile

I am using 20:04 desktop and have added some code to `.profile` to start `ssh-agent`. If this code is present, I get what appears to be a spurious error message saying that an error occurred. The script actually appears to have run properly and the correct contents have been loaded into ssh-agent and are usable. The only problem is the error message. The code I added to `.profile` is given below:

```
SSH_ENV="$HOME/.ssh/agent-environment"

function start_agent {
     OLD_UMASK=$(umask 077); /usr/bin/ssh-agent | sed 's/^echo/#echo/' > "${SSH_ENV}"; umask ${OLD_UMASK}
     source "${SSH_ENV}" > /dev/null
    /usr/bin/ssh-add "$HOME/.ssh/jfgphylis" </dev/null
   return $ret
}

# Source SSH settings, if applicable

if [ -f "${SSH_ENV}" ]; then
    . "${SSH_ENV}" > /dev/null
    #ps ${SSH_AGENT_PID} doesn't work under cywgin
    ps -ef | grep ${SSH_AGENT_PID} | grep ssh-agent$ > /dev/null || {
        start_agent;
    }
else
    start_agent;
fi
```

Can anyone explain why I am getting this behavior and is there any work-around?

Comment: This error is in the logs?

Comment: @George Udosen I can see nothing in the logs, just reports on the successful startup of various services.

Comment: Paste your code (or all of `.profile`) into https://www.shellcheck.net/

Comment: @waitinator
1. It does not support the use of environment variables used as in `SSH_ENV`.
2. It does not like scripts that write data to disk that is read back and used later.
I consider that the problems are associated in some way with the use of `ssh-agent` which has environmental requirements that are a bit complicated.

Comment: Not addressing your specific question but [Gnome keyring should be running an ssh-agent like program](https://wiki.gnome.org/Projects/GnomeKeyring/Ssh) already.  You shouldn't need to be starting up an instance manually.... assuming you're running vanilla Ubuntu Desktop.

Comment: @Brian Turek This needs to run on Ubuntu Server with multiple users logging in via SSH.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that the environment that runs `.profile` is a bit picky and it treats any output on stderr as representing an error. The command `ssh-add` uses `stderr` as if it was `stdout` and tells the world which `SSH keys` were loaded into `ssh-agent`. By invoking `ssh-add` in the following way the environment thought that everything was OK.

```
ssh-add key1 key2 1>&- 2>&-
```

What this does is to close `stdout` and `stderr` for any given command. This is the most efficient way of suppressing all output.